# Why is my PCA boomerang-shaped when normalizing?

Tags: pca, normalization

Running an unsupervised plot of my data, I noticed a hyperbolic ('boomerang') shape:

```
dim=2

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5, max_df = 0.4, stop_words = 'english')
train_tf_idf = vectorizer.fit_transform(bunch_train.data)
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=dim,random_state=42)
svd_train = svd.fit_transform(train_tf_idf)
svd_train = Normalizer().fit_transform(svd_train)

labels = {
        0:'alt.atheism',
        1:'comp.graphics',
        2:'sci.med'}
y = np.vectorize(labels.get)(bunch_train.target)

with plt.style.context('seaborn-whitegrid'):
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    for lab, col in zip(('alt.atheism', 'comp.graphics', 'sci.med'),
                        ('blue', 'red', 'green')):
        plt.scatter(svd_train[y==lab, 0],
                    svd_train[y==lab, 1],
                    label=lab,
                    c=col)

    plt.title('2D SVD on TF-IDF - 3-NewsGroups',size=28)
    plt.xlabel('PC1')
    plt.ylabel('PC2')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left',prop={'size': 20})
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

I suspect it has something to do with the Normalizer - when deleting the following line:

```
svd_train = Normalizer().fit_transform(svd_train)
```

the data plots like this:

[image]

Comment: it's not just an ellipse, it's the unit square; the obvious result of normalization! The aspect ratio of the plot is merely off.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are normalizing the output of SVD. It might be clear that this output does not need to be normalized if you consider the output of each step:

1. Vectorizer: [n_items x n_words] Matrix. Unnormalized.
2. TFIDF: [n_items x n_words] Matrix with rows [normalized](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting) to unit Euclidean norm.
3. SVD: [n_items x dim] Matrix. Columns correspond to each row's loading onto two orthonormal unit vectors.

In short, the output of the third step (SVD) is meaningful as-is and normalization obscures that meaning.

As to why the normalized output appears curved? The math to show this seems a bit involved but my intuition is that normalization is mapping the row weightings onto the [ellipsoid manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Geometric_meaning) used in SVD.